# SQL - How to search single row from a union table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just made a union table of a database table and a row of dummy data. And now I want to search for a single row:

```
select 
    '[Select Project]' as [Project], 'Die No' as [Die], 
    'Desc' as [Desc], '0' as [Accumulative], '0' as [Preventive], 
    '-' as PIC, 
    convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 111) as [E_Date] 

union all 

select 
    [Project], [Die], [Desc], [Accumulative], 
    [Preventive], PIC, [E_Date] 
from 
    [IOT].[dbo].[Project] 
where 
    [Project] = 'T00001'
```

However this returns the row `T00001` and the dummy row.

Is there a way to tell SQL to just return the row for `T00001` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it like this

```
SELECT * FROM

   (select '[Select Project]' as [Project], 'Die No' as [Die], 'Desc' as [Desc], 
    '0' as [Accumulative], '0' as [Preventive], '-' as PIC, 
    convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate(), 111) as [E_Date] 

union all 

    select [Project],[Die],[Desc], [Accumulative], 
    [Preventive], PIC, [E_Date] from [IOT].[dbo].[Project] ) a

where [Project] = 'T00001'
```